# Connect to a client that has dynamic IP address

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'm working on a server-client project. I hosted server on Google app engine so there is no problem with IP there, all the clients can connect to the server easily. Yet the problem occurs when I try to connect to a client, which is quite complex because I don't have static IP for the clients. Can anyone suggest me a good way for server-client coomucication in this case, without requiring that clients must have static IP address? 

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Well, obviously the client should register itself with the server and update it's IP when it changes.
There is, for example, [a program which does exactly that](http://www.noip.com/downloads.php?page=win) and then publishes the IP with a DNS.

But you should be aware that the IPv4 address space is not that big and a lot of internet clients do not own an IP (and work thru the ISP's [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation)). If you have clients that do not own an IP then you might want to stick to the usual [Pull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_technology): the clients should periodically issue a request to the server to check if there are new messages for them. With a [Keep-Alive connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) and an efficient server implementation the price of such checks might actually be low, although that kind of communication might not work very well with the GAE pricing.